# Python - Using the return variable of an awaited function Asyncio

Tags: python, mqtt, python-asyncio

I'm coding a small class that should be able to turn lights on when I receive an "ON" message from the mqtt broker. The issue I'm having is that the `conn()` function connects, and retrieves the message while the `on_message()` function awaits this. I haven't been able to use the message as I'm awaiting it and I cant find a solution to do this within the await (usually you just do `message = conn()`, when `conn()` returns the message). The code below was one of the attempts:

```
class SpaceCode:

    def __init__(self, subscription, broker):
        self.subscription = subscription
        self.broker = broker

    def turn_off(self, message):
        pass

    async def conn(self):
        async with Client(self.broker) as client:
            async with client.filtered_messages(self.subscription) as messages:
                await client.subscribe(self.subscription)
                async for message in messages:
                    return message

    async def main(self):
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(self.movement_detected(), timeout=900)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            turn_off(topic)

    async def movement_detected(self):
        await self.on_message()

    async def on_message(self):
        await self.conn()
        message = self.conn()
        if "ON" in str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")):  
            return str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
```

The error it returns then is "AttributeError:'coroutine' object has no attribute payload" which makes sense, I used a coroutine I did not await but even when just doing `await message = self.conn()` it will result in an error.

Comment: Maybe I understant you wrong, but did you know you could use assignment statement with awaitables? Like `message = await self.conn()`

Comment: `message.payload.decode("utf-8")` returns a string, you don't need to call `str` on it.

Comment: NobbyNobbs is correct. You put `await` in the wrong place. Remove `await self.conn()` and change `message = self.conn()` to `message = await self.conn()`.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs yes taht works! thanks a lot, i dont know how to mark this answer as correct but thank you

Comment: @ajayy to close you question can post your solution and mark that as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NobbyNobbs , the solution was to to await the coroutine and assign it to the variable at the same time. My version:

```
await self.conn()
message = self.conn()
```

The correct version:

```
await message = self.conn()
```